# converting big layout into bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, tablelayout

I'm trying to convert a tablelayout that represent a time table which can expand according to its content, into bitmap. 
the thing is that everything works fine with small layout (like size the screen size ) but with big layout 
it fails. 
I'm using this code to convert :

```
view = table;
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you assume with fails? Your app crashes, you get a faulty image?

Comment: i assume that because i get null pointer at bm (the bitmap) and the app crashes while trying to preview this bitmap

Comment: There is a limit for Bitmap size, usually 2048x2048 but it can be smaller so if you exceed this you need to find a way to split your image in more smaller ones

Comment: Do you really need this bitmap, or just want to make some performance optimizatinos?

Comment: i really need that birmap, its one of the main purpose of the my app.